# QCheckBox with label

Tags: c++11, qt5

I am working on a problem and I am stuck at this peculiar problem which is:

I have a horizontal layout and in that horizontal layout I have QcheckBox with label. The problem I am facing is, if I want to check and uncheck the check box it is working fine but if I click on the label which is on the right side of the checkbox its making checkbox check and uncheck(which is wrong). I want to set the checkable only to checkbox but not to label. Can anyone help me with this.

Note: programming language i am using is C++ and Qt.

Thanks & Regards,
Keshav

Comment: provide a  [mcve]

Comment: The simplest solution is to create two widgets, first is `QCheckbox` without text and the second is `QLabel` adhering to QCheckBox. If you want to make only box-indicator from `QCheckBox` checkable without label, you need to inherit from `QCheckBox` and override `hitButton` method. In `hitButton` you get box-indicator from QCheckBox by calling `style()->subElementRect` with `QStyle::SE_CheckBoxIndicator` and then test if `pos` as argument of `hitButton` is contained in box-indicator rect. If so, returns true, then checkbox is checked/unchecked only by clicking on box.

Comment: Thank you for your response but it would be great help to me if you could explain me problematically for your hitButton suggestion.